# Foursquare redirect uri has to be https?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, foursquare

I created new app on foursquare which I need to be redirected to my iOs application after login to foursquare.

I use BZFoursquare API. API's tutorial uses Custom URL Scheme but I can't write on foursquare application settings url that doesn't begin with http or https

Any idea?

Comment: Do your users login to Foursquare within the Foursquare iOS client or your own app?

Answer (score 0):

Host a website that will redirect users back into your app. If you want something super simple without the hassle you can try https://www.webscript.io/